# Apply the corr function to a matrix using levels of a factor?

Tags: r, correlation, weighted, tapply

I'm trying using the corr() function to calculate weighted ponderations. The way it works is the first argument should be a matrix with two columns corresponding to the two variables whose correlation we wish to calculate and the second a vector of weights to be applied to each pair of observations.

Here is an example.

```
> head(d)
 Shade_tolerance htot
1            4.56 25.0
2            2.73 23.5
3            2.73 21.5
4            3.97 17.0
5            4.00 25.5
6            4.00 23.5

> head(poids)
[1] 5.200440e-07 5.200440e-07 1.445016e-06 1.445016e-06 1.445016e-06 1.445016e-06

> corr(d,poids)
[1] 0.1357279
```

So I got it and I'm able to use it on my matrix but I would like to compute different correlations according to the levels of a factor. Let's say as if I was using the tapply() function.

```
> head(d2)
  Shade_tolerance htot idp
1            4.56 25.0  19
2            2.73 23.5  19
3            2.73 21.5  19
4            3.97 17.0  18
5            4.00 25.5  18
6            4.00 23.5  18
```

So my dream would be to do something like this:

```
tapply(as.matrix(d2[,c(1,2)]), d2$idp, corr)
```

Except that as you know in tapply() the first element needs to be avector not a matrix.

Would someone have any solution for me?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I just realized that I am missing the weights for the weighted correlation in the part of the data frame I showed you.
So it would have some how to take both the matrix and the weights according to the levels of the factor.

```
> head(df)
  Shade_tolerance htot idp        poids
1            4.56 25.0  19 5.200440e-07
2            2.73 23.5  19 5.200440e-07
3            2.73 21.5  19 1.445016e-06
4            3.97 17.0  19 1.445016e-06
5            4.00 25.5  19 1.445016e-06
6            4.00 23.5  19 1.445016e-06
```

I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a "huge" data.frame, then using `data.table` might help:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, "idp")
dt[, list(corr = corr(cbind(Shade_tolerance, htot), poids)), by=idp]

#    idp      corr
# 1:  18 0.9743547
# 2:  19 0.8387363
```

Comment: I just edited my question. I was missing one element to compute my weighted correlations. df$poids which are the weights have to be taken into account somewhere.

Comment: @Tom, if you've huge data, try out the `data.table` solution in the edit.

Comment: it would be faster than the ddply solution? I'll try it then. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom, yes indeed. If you've too many values for `idp`, you'll see the difference. With `data.table`, your bottleneck is almost just the "corr" function.

Comment: I have more than 44 000 values of idp. I'll run your solution and let you know.

Comment: Perfect. It worked and it was very fast. Thanks a lot. And no issue with the NAs, it just gave me NA for these values of idp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using function `ddply()` from library `plyr`.

```
ddply(df,.(idp),
   summarise,kor=corr(cbind(Shade_tolerance, htot),poids))
  idp       kor
1  18 0.9743547
2  19 0.8387363
```

Comment: I took the ddply solutions just because I was already using it on the huge df I have, but could not find how to figure this out. It is running (huge df), I'll let you know in a few minutes if it worked. The only thing I am a bit worried about is that I have NA in my df for some values of both Shade tolerance and htot and I don't think corr() can manage with NA.

Comment: @Tom I updated my solution - replaced as.matrix() with cbind() because as.matrix() gave strange results.

Comment: Ok. What do you think about the NAs issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using `by` and `cbind`,

```
 library(boot)
 by(dat,dat$idp,FUN=function(x)corr(cbind(x$Shade_tolerance,x$htot),x$poids))
dat$idp: 18
[1] 0.9743547
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$idp: 19
[1] 0.7474093
```

Comment: Strange, I gave a `by` solution as well, but it doesn't appear in my "rollbacks".